# How to conditionally format a cell in a [gt] table based on the value of the cell

Tags: r, gt

The `gt` package lets users easily format cells [based on conditional statements](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html#examples) about the rows. I'm looking for a way to format each cell based on the value in the cell.

Here's what I mean. In the table below, I'd like to color each cell with S&P values by the value it contains.

```
library(gt)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# some arbitrary values of the S&P 500
jan08 <- sp500 %>% 
  filter(between(date, as.Date("2008-01-01"), as.Date("2008-01-15"))) %>%
  select(date, open, high, low, close)

gt(jan08)
```

[image: basic gt table]

This function returns the appropriate color name for each value as a character string.

```
## this is the range of values
sp500.range <- jan08 %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(open, high, low, close))
heat_palette <- leaflet::colorNumeric(palette = "YlOrRd",
                                      domain = sp500.range$value)

# For example:
> heat_palette(1411.88)
[1] "#FEB852"
```

Each cell can be colored manually, but this obviously isn't practical.

```
gt(jan08) %>%
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = heat_palette(1411.88)),
            locations = cells_body(columns = "open", 
                                   rows = (open == 1411.88)))
```

[image: gt with filled cell]

Is there a way to use the `tab_style` function to conditionally fill cells based on the value of the cell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create the `gt` object first and then loop over the sequence of rows in a `for` loop to color as the `color` argument in `cell_fill` takes a value of `length` 1

```
library(gt)
gtobj <- gt(jan08)
ht_values <- heat_palette(jan08$open)
for(i in seq_along(jan08$open)) {
   gtobj <- gtobj %>%
         tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = ht_values[i]),
                   locations = cells_body(columns = "open", rows = i))
}



gtobj
```

-output

[image]

EDIT:
This `for` loop can then be placed in a function like this.

```
fill_column <- function(gtobj, column){
  ht_values <- heat_palette(jan08 %>% pull(sym(column)))
  for(i in seq_along(jan08 %>% pull(sym(column)))){
    gtobj <- gtobj %>%
      tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = ht_values[i]),
                locations = cells_body(columns = column, rows = i))
  }
  gtobj
}
```

Then, this function can be included with a pipe.

```
gt(jan08) %>%
  fill_column("open") %>%
  fill_column("high") %>%
  fill_column("low") %>%
  fill_column("close")
```

[image: gt table with all columns filled]

Comment: This is great, @akrun. Thank you. I took your answer and put the `for` loop into a function. Do you mind if I edit your answer to include this? Then I'll accept it.

Comment: One modification to the `column_fill` function to make it completely self-contained, reference the dataframe from the `gtobj`. I.e. `gtobj$\`_data\``

Comment: @fe108 Please check the OP's code