# How do I conditionally format based off another cell in gt()?

Tags: r, gt

Am I missing something to do this with gt()?

[image]

Seems straight forward but the closest [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944953/how-to-conditionally-format-a-cell-in-a-gt-table-based-on-the-value-of-the-cel) I find still references it's own cell. I would like to stick with gt() if possible as *ALL* my other tables use it and I would like to have some consistency between reports.

```
dat <- data.frame(obs1 = LETTERS[1:5],
                  value1 = 1:5,
                  obs2 = LETTERS[6:10],
                  value2 = 5:1)

dat |>
  gt() |>
  ???
```

Comment: See linked post, we need *data_color*: `dat |> gt() |> data_color(columns = "value1", target_columns = "obs1") |> data_color(columns = "value2", target_columns = "obs2")`

Comment: I spent the last hour searching for an answer and knew it had to be out there somewhere. Thanks!