# Styling cells in a gt table based on detection of a string in their contents

Tags: r, gt

I am using the gt() package in R and am having a rough time trying to style my cells based on their content.

Here's a minimal example.

Let's start with a tibble, `my_data`:

```
  my_data <- tibble(person = c('pablo','spots','harry'), 
                    outcome_1 = c('good','bad','good'),
                    outcome_2 = c('good','good','bad'))
```

Let's now try to render a gt table and color the cells that contain the text 'bad' so that they're red.

```
  my_data |> 
    gt() |>
    
    tab_style(
      
      style = list(
        cell_fill(color = 'red'),
        cell_text(weight = 'bold')),
      
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = starts_with('outcome_'),
        rows = contains('bad')
      )
    )
```

But it doesn't work! The cells containing the word 'bad' should have bold font weight and should have a red background. Instead I get...

[image: unstyled cells]

The example in the docs for [`locations`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/tab_style.html?q=tab_style#examples) seems fairly straightforward. I am following what it says in for [`cells_body`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/cells_body.html) usage and as far as I can tell correctly applying the [selection helpers](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html) `starts_with` and `contains`.

So what's the problem? I think I got a fundamental misunderstanding here of how this is supposed to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sort of hackish but doing its job:

```
my_data |> 
  gt() |>
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_fill(color = 'red'),
      cell_text(weight = 'bold')),
    locations = names(my_data)[grep('outcome', names(my_data))] |>
      lapply(FUN = \(col_name){
        cells_body(columns = col_name,
                   rows = grepl('bad', my_data[[col_name]])
                   )
      })
    )
  )
```

It works because you can supply a *list* of `cells_body` selections, which is what `lapply` produces (here as an inline call).

Comment: Thank you! I've upvoted will accept if there's no more compact version. I just can't remember all that, it looks really complicated. The examples which just apply colors to a range of values are so simple-looking. I am hoping this could be simple too.

Comment: You're welcome. The following solution (although from Sept. 2020, but then again, by @akrun) suggests there's no straightforward indexing by cell content alone: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63945239/20513099